# How to index a string array

Tags: c#

I have a string array in C# 3.5:

```
string [] times = new[] {“08:00 am” , “10:00 am”, “120”} ;
```

I would like to create indexes to times: `StartTime`, `EndTime` , `ElapsedTime` so that when I code:

```
StartTime= “09:00 am” ; 
EndTime= “11:00 am” ;
```

then `times[0]` is set to `“09:00 am”` , etc.

I could create 3 methods:

```
private void StartTime(string time)
{    times[0] = time;  }
private void EndTime(string time)
{    times[1] = time;  }
private void ElapsedTime(string time)
{    times[2] = time;   }
```

and code

```
StartTime("09:00");
```

but is there a simpler way to do it?

Comment: Why are you using an array when you should really have this in a class itself with private members?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What you should really do is create a new class to do this.  Make the two times properties.

And the time elapsed is a function of the start and end times.

```
class Time 
{
    public DateTime StartTime{ get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime{ get; set; }

    public String[] ToStringArray() 
    {
        String[] ret = new String[3];
        ret[0] = StartTime.ToString();
        ret[1] = EndTime.ToString();
        ret[2] = ElapsedTime().ToString();
        return ret;
    }

    public TimeSpan ElapsedTime() 
    {
        return EndTime.subtract(StartTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 show him a public property that returns all 3 in a string array and then it would be the perfect solution :)

Comment: @Matt: I would say it was well earned (and it's 95 when I write this).

Comment: It is a good lesson in code design.  Make your code model what you are trying to do.

Comment: I added a return statement to ToStringArray(), I assume this is still necessary in C#3.0, but please remove if I am wrong

Comment: @Patrick I didn't want that method to actually work. But thanks for the fix! `:P`

Comment: I was kidding btw.  I suck at writing code that compiles if I don't have a modern IDE.  I always miss the easy stuff like that.

Comment: ElapsedTime should "return EndTime.Subtract (StartTime);". The casing errors will make the class fail compilation.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know it it is simpler, but I would suggest taking the hard index references out of your code and replace them with constants, to make easier to maintain if the order of elements in the array would change in the future:

```
private const int START_TIME = 0;
private const int END_TIME = 1;
private const int ELAPSED_TIME = 2;
```

Then you will also get more readable code:

```
times[END_TIME] = time;
```

Unless you want to be more object oriented, in which case you should follow jjnguy's advice.

Answer (score 2):

To add to jjnguy's answer, you should really have a class that holds the 3 properties, and then if you need an array you could have a public property that just has a getter and returns the 3 different times in a string array.

Comment: I added that functionality to my example.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

How about an extension method?

```
public static class Extensions
{
   public static void StartTime(this string[] array, string value)
   {
      array[0] = value;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a dictionary.

e.g.

```
Dictionary<string, string> times = new Dictionary<string, string>();
times.Add("StartTime","09:00am");
times.Add("EndTime","11:00am");
```