# How do I perform this MutliArray setup in Java?

Tags: java, php, android, arrays, arraylist

I come from a PHP background and I'm just getting my teeth into some Java. I was wondering how I could implement the following in Java as simply as possible, just echoing the results to a terminal via the usual "`System.out.print()`" method.

```
<?php
$Results[0]['title'] = "No Country for Old Men";
$Results[0]['run_time'] = "122 mins";
$Results[0]['cert'] = "15";
$Results[1]['title'] = "Old School";
$Results[1]['run_time'] = "88 mins";
$Results[1]['cert'] = "18";

// Will basically show the above in order.
foreach($Results as value) {
     echo $Results[$value]['title'];
     echo $Results[$value]['run_time'];
     echo $Results[$value]['cert'];
}

// Lets add some more as I need to do this in Java too

$Results[2]['title'] = "Saving Private Ryan";
$Results[2]['run_time'] = "153 mins";
$Results[2]['cert'] = "15";

// Lets remove the first one as an example of another need
$Results[0] = null;
?>
```

I hear there are "list iterators" or something that are really good for rolling through data like this. Perhaps it could be implemented with that?

A fully working `.java` file would be most handy in this instance, including how to add and remove items from the array like the above.

P.S. I do plan on using this for an Android App in the distant future, so, hopefully it should all work on Android fine too, although, I imagine this sort of thing works on anything Java related :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I were doing that in Java I would make the following changes:

1. Make a `Movie` class that encapsulates the data about a movie
2. Use `List`s instead of native arrays

A `Movie` class may look something like this:

```
public class Movie {

    public final String title;
    public final int runtime;
    public final int cert;

    public Movie(String title, int runtime, int cert) {
        this.title = title;
        this.runtime = runtime;
        this,cert = cert;
    }
}
```

Then you could make a List of Movies like so:

```
List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<Movie>();
movies.add(new Movie("Some Movie", 120, 15);
movies.add(new Movie("Another Movie", 90, 18);
```

You can remove Movies like so:

```
movies.remove(0);
```

And you can iterate through them like so:

```
for (Movie m: movies) {
    System.out.println("Title: " + m.title + 
                       ", Runtime: " + m.runtime + 
                       ", Cert: " + m.cert);
}
```

If you wanna get specific things out of the List, you can do the following:

```
Movie the2ndOne = movies.get(1);
System.out.println("Title: " + the2ndOne.title); // or
System.out.println("Title: " + movies.get(0).title);
```

To view an entire `List` simply do:

```
System.out.println(movies.toString());
```

*Note:* This assumes that the `Movie` class has an intelegent `toString()` method written for it.

For some more reference on `List`s that I showed above, check out the [javadocs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) on them.

When writing in a OO language, you should use OO principles.

It may also be helpful to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159582/how-to-index-a-string-array/1159604#1159604) question and my answer to it.  It is very similar in that you two are both trying to do things with arrays that would better be served using classes.

Comment: @Justin: you beat me by a minute! :)
+1 because your code is complete

Comment: @Samuh, ha.  Actually you beat me by ~35 seconds.

Comment: This looks ace!! Thank-you very much for that!

One final question though, can I still echo out specific things once they are inside the list??

In PHP I would usually do something like:

<?php
// Picked random things here

echo $Results[1]['run_time']; // Echos "88mins"
echo $Results[0]['title];     // Echos "No Country For Old Men"

?>

Comment: Yup, I'm gonna edit my answer to add some more info.  But in short use `list.get(index)` to get a specific element. @Andy

Comment: I have a final question about this. In PHP there is a Print_r function which shows me the entire array. Is there a similar method that would work so I can get a simple string of the entire list (including all added movies)?

Otherwise, this works absolutely perfectly!!!

Comment: @Andy To do that you would need to override the `toString()` method of Movie.  Create that method, then call `System.out.println(movies.toString())`

Comment: How to you mean by intelligent? Any change of an example or is it fairly complex??

I assume something along the lines of:

<code>
@Override
    public String toString() {
    return this.studio;
}
</code

Comment: @Andy, it is not hard.  You are very close to correct.  `public String toString(){ return "Title: " + m.title + ", Runtime: " + m.runtime + ", Cert: " + m.cert; }`

Comment: @Andy, something like that will mat a Movie.toString() return a well formatted string.  The List toString will then use that toString from Movie when it gets printed out.

Answer (score 2):

You can first create a class defining the Data Structure and then build an `ArrayList` of these object to actually store values. `ArrayList` is one of many `Collection` available in Java and provides many methods to iterate over them and add or delete items.

For e.g.: your class could look like:

```
class Movie{

String title;
String run_time;
String cert;
...//getter,setter methods for these instance variables/fields
}

// you then create movie objects and populate some data in them
Movie one = new Movie();

one.setTitle("No Country for..");
one.setRunTime("122 mins");
one.setCert("15");

//create arrayList to store movie objects
ArrayList<Movie> list = new ArrayList<Movie>();

//add item to list
list.add(one);

// iterate over arrayList to get values
for(Movie item:list){
System.out.println(item.getTitle());
}
```

Reference: [ArrayList](http://www.baskent.edu.tr/~tkaracay/ders/prg/java/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)